# Google Apps Script Error all of a sudden? cannot reach property from undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting this error at the line with the if statement.

I did change the name of the sheet at some point. Will that affect my script?
Link to the script - https://script.google.com/d/1DX3bAyb63Bio6gEsLIIrnUB0B7MDSfJ1FzB97Mpul9Tu9m6UzjDiBSjg/edit?usp=sharing

> TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 21, file "Code")

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheetToWatch= 'Connections', //name of the sheet here.
columnToWatch = 8, columnToStamp = 25;
   if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch || e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getName() !== sheetToWatch || !e.value) return;
   e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
       .setValue(new Date());
}


function onEdit2(e) {

var sheetToWatch= 'Connections', //name of the sheet here.
columnToWatch = 8, columnToStamp = 25, columnToStampUser=26;
   if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch || e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getName() !== sheetToWatch || !e.value) return;
   e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStamp)
       .setValue(new Date());
    e.source.getActiveSheet()
       .getRange(e.range.rowStart, columnToStampUser)
       .setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
}
```

Comment: You can only have one onEdit function, put the second in a conditional

Comment: I have deleted the second onEdit function but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

OK. It's fine. You have to call as the trigger of EDIT event

Like a standalone trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
  onEdit2(e);
}
```

Or you can register `onEdit2` as an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) via menu

If you rename a sheet then you have to change line `var sheetToWatch= 'Connections'`. Replace `'Connections'` with your new sheet name.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. When I say sheet, I mean the name of the google sheets file.
I have another function onEdit(e) which gives the same error. Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Sorry but there are no other objects with `range` property. Could you share full file?

Comment: https://script.google.com/d/1DX3bAyb63Bio6gEsLIIrnUB0B7MDSfJ1FzB97Mpul9Tu9m6UzjDiBSjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but this works perfectly for me. You can't run this function from the script editor. This code is invoked automatically when an user makes edits.

Comment: I tried running invoking it through the sheet also...but it didn't work..
created a new sheet...can you please see what am I doing wrong here?
Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/108YfpOIn6t1D4LdD8rambm7Bfp5QuuZwhF836YWf6do/edit?usp=sharing
Script - https://script.google.com/d/1ss2vflNFaiSWhevLa7ltAp_NHB4mN6XnrwhymwaRkL8tzCDg5agZzv71/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry I can't debug it here.